# How to know whether the created view is valid or not

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I am new to db.

Lets say I have created a view with force.

So how can I get know whether the view created is invalid or not?

I mean are there any queries from which I can get to know the validity status of the view?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Oracle dictionary view `user_objects`:

```
select object_name, status from user_objects 
where object_type = 'VIEW' and object_name = 'YOUR_VIEW';
```

If the table on which the view is based is altered for any reason, you may have to recompile the view. For example, if a table’s structure is altered, such as by a change to a column’s datatype, or perhaps if a column is dropped from the table altogether - a column that is used
by the view — then it may change the status of the view to 'INVALID'.

Also note that there are there versions of "all objects" view:

`USER_OBJECTS` - all objects owned by a current user;
`ALL_OBJECTS` - all objects on which a current user has any privileges;
`DBA_OBJECTS` - all database objects (you would need special privileges to access this view)

ALL_ and DBA_ versions have an additional column `OWNER` containing the owner of the object.

These "naming rules" are applied to the different Oracle dictionary views: [USER_ | ALL_ | DBA_] [INDEXES | TABLES | VIEWS | etc]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this helps:

```
SELECT object_name,
       status
  FROM user_objects
 WHERE object_type = 'VIEW';
```

or (for views in all schemas)

```
SELECT owner,
       object_name,
       status
  FROM all_objects
 WHERE object_type = 'VIEW';
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from checking the status about that new view in the dictionary, you can do:

```
 select 1 from OWNER.MY_NEWLY_CREATED_VIEW;
```

or

```
 select count(*) from OWNER.MY_NEWLY_CREATED_VIEW;
```

Whatever the statement of your new view, from that feedback you know it works or not.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle docs include the following as a way to update or find out if a view is invalid:

Recompile the view e.g. customer_ro via the following statement:

ALTER VIEW customer_ro
COMPILE;
If Oracle Database encounters no compilation errors while recompiling customer_ro, then customer_ro becomes valid. If recompiling results in compilation errors, then the database returns an error and customer_ro remains invalid.