# How to find invalid views?

Tags: sql-server, view

How do I find any views that are invalid (because the view was created without 'with schema binding') and one or more of the underlying columns were changed? This is for SQL Server 2012.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26967458/how-to-know-whether-the-created-view-is-valid-or-not

Comment: @Saeidsamadidana . . . One presumes this is SQL Server from the phrasing of the question, but the OP should really specify clearly.

Answer (score 0):

You could generate script with all views definitions with SSMS and run it as it is - probably you'll get some compile errors.

or try something like this:

```
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @sql = ((
SELECT 'select top 1 v.* from ' + quotename(object_schema_name(o.object_id)) + '.' + QUOTENAME(o.name) + ' v
'
FROM sys.objects o
WHERE o.type = 'V'
ORDER BY o.name
FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'varchar(max)'))

PRINT @sql

/* exec @sql */
```